# Setting navigation bar button style for "More" tab in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I cannot seem to change the style for the navigation bar button stye. Here is what I am getting.

[image]

I subclassed UINavigationController and did the following:

```
- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    self = [super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    if (self) 
    {
        UINavigationBar *navBar = [self navigationBar];
        [navBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        [navBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

I am running iOS 4.3 and the button is added automatically by the OS when there is more than 4 tabs present in the UITabBarController.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you have to explain what your target is also right? :) People can't tell you how do it if you don't tell them what you want to accomplish...

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you on?

Comment: What it is that you are trying to show in a different style?  I am assuming the 'Edit' button, but the code for that button is not shown.  Are you adding this button programmatically or through Interface Builder?

Comment: I am running iOS 4.3 and the button is added automatically by the OS when there is more than 4 tabs present in the UITabBarController.

Comment: Why not just do it all in the nib file, as that will keep the colours consistent?

Comment: @MSgambel, what is wrong with my method?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but you may have to set the colour of the UIBarButtonItem to have the same colour as the whole navBar. In the nib, this is taken care of for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the more navigation controller is handled by the OS, this is what you have to do.

```
[self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: David is correct here.  Though I should point out that you will likely want to do something else to your bar other than set the tintColor.

Access it via tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.  I'd suggest adjusting the layer properties to get more custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's adding that by itself, I think you need to change self.navigationItem or self.navigationController to what you want, not just your custom one?

Comment: How am I suppose to control the style of the `More` navigation items? It is part of the `More` tab, which is created automatically.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, set the style of the `self.whatever`, and it'll change the style of the More button. The button it's adding is subscribing to the properties of `self`, so you have to change the styles there. Do you get what I'm trying to say?

Comment: For example, `self.navigationItem.RightBarButtonItem`.